# How to add some more feature for this simulink model

Tags: control, robotic-arm, matlab, simulation

After some research
[Robotic hand simulation in MatLab?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/18327/robotic-hand-simulation-in-matlab)

After some motivation, I have tried to go inside Matlab Simulink and was able to do this :-
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gdjzYNefG7teaU3FOkQAYTg3q7cRuhV5

With this thing I was able to control the whole palm. As you can see here.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LU7148l99LvJsWYpY7CRP1FWwsZpUqiR

But i want to add some MASK or more control to restrict the movement or may be picking an object.

Can anyone help me how to move for more advance control that i may don't know.

Comment: If anyone can show some advance control for that SINGLE FINGER would be really appreciated.

Comment: I have uploaded the files already. If anyone interested in showing some interesting feature then that would be greatly helpfull.